# parse multiline Json - array instead of row

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, jsonparser

I have the following json:

```
   {
      "data": {
        "data2": [],
        "data3": [
          {
            "info": {
              "test1": "value1",
              "test2": "value2"
            },
            "info2": [
              {
                "info": {
                  "test1": "value3",
                  "test2": "value4"
    },
          {
                "info": {
                  "test1": "value5",
                  "test2": "value6"
    }
              
            ]
          }
    ]
}}
```

I need to extract info2.info.test1, info2.info.test2 into columns.
I've parsed it in a spark but I have an array column instead of single rows:

```
df = json.select(
      explode("data.data3.info2").alias("json"),
).select(
       col("json.info.test1"),
       col("json.info.test2")
)
```

Expected output:

```
| test1    | test2          |
| -------- | -------------- |
| value3   | value4         |
| value5   | value6         |
```

Comment: Can you please check your provided JSON file? Looks like it corrupted. Btw, it would be good to see an expected output.

Comment: your json seems to be wrong, can you please double check it and also advise how the expected output looks like?

Comment: I've added changes, thanks for comments.

Answer (score 0):

My working solution:

```
df = json.select(
      explode("data.data3.info2").alias("json"),
).select(
      explode("json.info").alias("info")
).select(
       col("info.test1"),
       col("info.test2")
)
```